# matching string to filenames with regex (java 1.6)

Tags: java, regex

I have a bunch of images with names such as nineDiamonds.gif and aceHearts.gif along with a "Card" class for playing card faces.

In the constructor, I want to pass a String of the card name and be able to create a JPanel with the right image. Easy enough, but I want to be able to pass things such as:

- "9 of hearts" => nineHearts.gif
- "9 hearts" => nineHearts.gif
- "nine of Hearts" => nineHearts.gif
- Integer.toString(9) + "hearts" => nineHearts.gif
- Integer.toString(1) + "hearts" => aceHearts.gif
- "Ace of hearts" => aceHearts.gif

I understand I can overload the constructor and match things up with a switch and what not, but what I am really after is am elegant, functional style solution, something along the lines of:

```
String fileName = name.replaceAll("magic regex") + ".gif";
```

Thanks!

Comment: How is this regex solution more elegant than doing it properly?

Comment: @ryanprayogo what is properly?

Comment: Ok, so this is turned into a negation of entire words issue of which there are several well answered questions already. But Im still not getting it to work: String s = "1 of hearts"; System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[[\\s\\S]&&[^1-9]&&[^(?!.*diamonds).*$]]","")) ==> "1oas". Shouldnt the "oas" be stripped off by the "[\\s\\S]"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `.replaceAll()` is not going to be enough.

Lowercase your string. `(\S+)\s*(?:of)?\s*(hearts|clubs|diamonds|spades)` will parse `9 of hearts` and `9hearts` to ("9", "hearts"), and `aceofclubs` to ("ace", "clubs"). Create a map that maps "1" to "ace", ... "13" to "king"; pass first groups of the match through it. Then creation of the filename becomes trivial.

Comment: I think you meant `(\d+)` at the beginning, not `(\s+)`.

Comment: Ok so now I have a map of 100+ lines with stuff like "cardImageMap.put("1clubs", new ImageIcon("cardImages/aceClubs.gif"));" - I think its just fine, but is there anything wrong with a strat such as "s = s.replaceAll("13", "king").replaceAll("12", "queen").replaceAll("hearts", "Hearts");" ?

Comment: @Tom s = s.replace... 13 times when only 1 is necessary think about it for a second, also 2 for loops will shorten your map creation code

Comment: @Tom: yes, there are certain problems. I only meant a map of 13 entries, replacing numerical values with canonical names, so that "1 of clubs". becomes "aceClubs.gif". You split the input into 2 parts using my regexp; match's `.group(1)` is rank, `.group(2)` is suit. If rank is all digits, map it to a name. Then upper-case the first character of suit and combine it all.

Comment: I've removed the typos from the regex, now it actually works :)

Comment: @Liviu T. Thanks... yes if using the regex, I would condense the calls - i was just trying to make a point about using regex or regex and map.

Comment: @9000 I think i misunderstand your direction. I want to remove all the char except the number (9 or nine) and except the suite. Something like .replaceAll("[[\\s\\S]&&[^1-9]&&[^(<hearts>|<clubs>|<diamonds>|<spades>)]]","")); seems to be along the way, but the negation is matching char and not words and i have not added one, two, three, ect. I'm currently trying to understand the lookarounds - with out success, and including a bunch of match words questions at stack. I must be missing a fundamental.

Comment: "ace of hearts => aceHearts" is much more beneficial than "ace of hearts => (ace, hearts)".

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tips that should get you to a working solution:

- Strip the word "of" using a regular expression with word boundaries (`\bof\b`)
- Replace numeric strings with their respective words (can be done with a map defining the numbers (e.g. `map[9] = "nine"`) and a for loop)
- Use `String.split()` to split at word boundaries, then capatalise the all but the first word and re-join

So in the end, a regular expression alone is not the best solution as is often the case.